# Instalation python2.7 in virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, wsgi, trac

Some day I lost access to Trac which is Python2.7 software. (I suppose, that deprecation of Python2.x is clue). There is Python3 unstable version, but I can't use it, because there's no plugins yes, which are key for my Trac installation.

So created virtual environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 env
```

And finally installation is succesful!

```
pip install trac
```

But... Stil can't run it by wsgi apache2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/trac/apache/trac.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
    import trac.web.main
  File "/var/lib/trac/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/web/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from trac.web.api import *
  File "/var/lib/trac/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/web/api.py", line 18, in <module>
    from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
```

I tried to install `pip install http` but still the same problem

my wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

import os

os.environ['PKG_RESOURCES_CACHE_ZIP_MANIFESTS'] = '1'
os.environ['TRAC_ENV_PARENT_DIR'] = '/var/lib/trac'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/lib/trac/eggs'

#import trac.db.postgres_backend
#trac.db.postgres_backend.PostgreSQLConnection.poolable = False

import trac.web.main

application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

How to change wsgi or how to install missing module?

Comment: Looks like you didn't post the full error traceback?